# How to set jQuery mouseleave function for multiple divs with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site that has multiple divs with the same id name. I want to set a mouseleave function for all of the divs that have this id. In my `$(document).ready` function I have this code...

```
$('#my_post_container').mouseleave(function(e)
{
    hideSnippet();
});
```

My `hideSnippet()` function is correct, but doing this only set the mouseleave function for the first time that a div comes up of id `my_post_container`. Is there a way to set the mouseleave function to all divs with this id?

Comment: you should not have multiple divs with the same ID. it is bad HTML.

Comment: Ids have to be unique. Use a class instead. That will also solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a site that has multiple divs with the same id name.

Then you need to fix that. You **must not** have more than one element with the same `id`. [`id` values **must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

You probably want to use [`class` instead](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes), at which point your code is basically fine:

```
$('.my_post_container').mouseleave(function(e)
{
    hideSnippet();
});
```

...although it coudl be shortened a bit if `hideSnippet` doesn't care what arguments it gets, doesn't care about `this`, and doesn't return `false`:

```
$('.my_post_container').mouseleave(hideSnippet);
```

Comment: I could change my code so each block is a class instead of an ID, but this still doesn't help with my problem. If it were a class, could I set the mouseleave function for each div that uses the class?

Comment: +1 But wow you can you be this fast? :) with all those links etc.? :)

Comment: @jas7457: *"...but this still doesn't help with my problem."* Actually, it does, because when you switch to using a class (on the elements, and in the selector), your code works. The only reason it doesn't work is that `id` values have to be unique, and so jQuery only hooks up the handler to one of them.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: I've done this before. :-) I keep the HTML5 spec link handy.

Comment: Hehe. Now I need to create a stack of pre-compiled answers that will fit a lot of questions. :D

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Oh, I don't do that. Just the reference material. :-)

Comment: I was just kidding. No offense. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response!

Answer (score 2):

It is invalid HTML to have multiple objects with the same id.  As such, you cannot use normal selectors to find them all and you should fix your HTML to not do that.

The #1 suggestion is to fix the HTML so it does not have multiple objects with the same ID.  Use a class name and you can then select them all with `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` or with jQuery selectors as in:

```
$('.my_post_container')
```

If you insist on having multiple objects with the same id (a bad choice), then you will have to somewhat manually iterate over all possible objects that could have that id.

```
$("div[id='my_post_container']");
```

But, this is pretty darn inefficient because the browser can't use any of the built-in selector engine logic and it could break in the future if jQuery decides to optimize this.  You really ought to switch to using class names.

Comment: Lol, when I read illegal, I thought you were about to say "delete it now before you get arrested" :)

Comment: @mattytommo: :-) Yeah, "invalid" is the more accurate term. ("Illegal" is just fine too, though...)

Comment: OK, changed it to invalid.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's better, +1 for you :)

Comment: @jfriend00: Although `$("div[id='my_post_container']");` ***may*** find more than one element with that `id`, there's no guarantee that it will, for the simple reason that A) jQuery may at any time optimize that behavior out, and B) a browser is entirely free to ignore the `id` attribute and not assign it to the element if the `id` is already in use. So I would strongly recommend leaving that bit off. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I don't recommend it either as I say several times in my answer (four different places), but it does work in IE, Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sV5vW/.  Yes, it could break in the future which is why the OP should fix their HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have multiple elements on the same page with the same `id`. Use a `class` instead, as shown here:

HTML:

```
<div class="my_post_container">...</div>
<div class="my_post_container">...</div>
<div class="my_post_container">...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.my_post_container').mouseleave(function(e)
{
    hideSnippet();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there should not be any div elements with same ID name.. first we should solve that by keeping class name same.

then on mouse leave and enter part..

```
 $(".testClass").on({
  mouseenter : function() {
          $(this).css({"background-color" : "blue"});
  },
  mouseleave : function() {
          $(this).css({"background-color" : "green"});
  }
 });
```

this should work.. will add a js sample http://jsfiddle.net/meVc6/

and the same thing can be achived using css too..

just add css `.testClass:hover { background-color:blue}`